# URI format not supported - trying to get the folder size

Tags: c#, asp.net

Our Web application saves files to a folder and before adding a new file, we want to get the size of the folder. This folder is on a different drive on the same server.
It throws an error saying " URI format not supported.".

If I hardcode the path, I am not getting any error. However, if I pass the path in a variable, it throws an error.

```
public static long GetDirectorySize(string pathofFile)
{

    string localPath;
    localPath = new Uri(pathofFile).ToString();

    string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@localPath, "*.*"); -- ERROR here
    //string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\ClientFiles\CITYLOC\", "*.*"); -- Hardcoded value works

    long fldSize = 0;
    foreach (string name in allFiles )
    {
        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(name);
        fldSize += info.Length;
    }

    return fldSize;
}

Value of pathofFile : D:\ClientFiles\CITYLOC\
Error: URI format not supported.
```

Comment: `localPath` will start with a `file://` prefix which is not correct, why are you not just using `pathofFile` ?

Comment: Thanks. That helped.